# Scrolling within one div automatically triggers scrolling to relevant paragraphs in other divs?

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I am working on a project that involves three scrollable divs containing some paragraphs of text. Some of the paragraphs in the texts can be loosely associated with each other. What I would like to happen is that if a reader scrolls to a particular paragraph within say, the first div, the other two divs automatically scroll to the relevant paragraphs in the texts they contain. That way, the three paragraphs will be displayed at once, while the reader can decided for himself which div/text he wants to explore further by scrolling down. Can this be achieved by using a JQuery plugin and how do I implement it?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: I have some basic knowledge of HTML/CSS, but I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possible with jQuery (without a plugin) and to do this you will probably need to handle the onscroll event of each of the divs.

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rMEw/) demonstrating the below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ScrollingDiv').scroll(function() {
        var CurScrollHeight = $(this).scrollTop();
        //alert('in scroll');
        $('.ScrollingDiv').each(function() {
            //alert('in each');
            $(this).scrollTop(CurScrollHeight);
        });
    });
});
```

This code applies a handler to the onscroll function of every element with a class of `ScrollingDiv` on the page, when one of the elements scrolls it will find all the other elements and set the scroll height to be the same.

What you will need to do for your situation is come up with a way to determine the scroll height required to view the paragraphs in each div, i.e. 1st div might be 200px height, 2nd might be 400px height, 3rd might be 150px height etc...

Once you have this simply change the code I have supplied to fit your functionality. You will probably need to set the ID of the divs and find the individual elements and get the correct height for the paragraphs you require.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to avoid having to use fixed heights for the divs, i.e. work with a kind of waypoints? For instance, If waypoint 1 passes the top of div 1, div 2 automatically scrolls to the waypoint that is related to it? This would be useful I have to make changes to the text.

Comment: So I need to find a way to get this into the proper code: if #div1 Scrolltop (VALUE1) then #div2 Scrolltop (VALUE2), with VALUE1 = distance from top to paragraph 1 in div1 and VALUE2 e.g. distance from top to paragraph3 in div2

Comment: This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rMEw/2/) is the best I have managed, I'm afraid I can't really help more than this. There is a problem with this when trying to re-bind the onscroll event.

Comment: I am new to all of this, so it will take me some time to figure out your code. But i am wondering whether there isn't a more simple way of doing this. e.g. something along the lines of: if ($(#div1).scrollTop()=300){$(#div2).scrollTo()=100}   Or am I completely missing the point here?

Comment: If you know the physical positions of your divs then you can simply set the scroll height of the div with `scrollTop(Position);` I was creating my code on the assumption the text would not be fixed, as you would need to manually change this code every time the text changed.

Comment: Could you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a better example of what you are trying to accomplish and write the code of what you think should make sense, I'll then try to help from there.

Comment: I have corrected your JSFiddle, hopefully that will help you more with your solution. The new JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SgNpP/4/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SgNpP/8/ One final question and then I'll leave you be, many thanks!

Comment: Answered :), Please rate up if it helped you :)

Comment: You got it! I am afraid I do not yet have sufficient reputation points, but I certainly accepted your answer if that helps!